# Aws instance showing more disk space then the root volume

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04

I am running couple of aws ec2 ubuntu instances, today I just checked "df -h" I discovered that, there is a partition in the volume, it says I have got about 355GB of the space, its not the root volume. '/mnt' volume is mounted in that particular volume which says '/dev/sdb', just out of curiosity I want to know what does it do? Can I remove that partition from the volume? or Can I use that partition to deploy my code? Help me with the heads up.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what AWS calls an ephemeral volume, or an instance store. It is not an EBS volume, just space on the machine that hosts your instance. Different size EC2 instances have different amounts of storage available (micro instances have none). Some AMIs don't mount these volumes automatically; it looks like your Ubuntu AMI does.

Go ahead and use it for things like scratch space and deployment. You can use it for anything at all, actually. But realize that it isn't as robust as an EBS volume, and it will vanish whenever your instance is stopped. Also, AWS says that instance stores have poorer random access behavior than EBS volumes, though better sequential read and write behavior.